# Proving "s" is supermum if and only if $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ | \exists a \in A : a > s-\epsilon $

Tags: calculus

Let $ A \subseteq \mathbb{R}  \ $ and $ A \notin \emptyset \ $. Let $ s \in \mathbb{R} $ so that $ s $ is an upperbound ($ s \geq a$).

Prove that $ s $ is the supermum of $ A $ if and only if $ \forall \epsilon > 0  \ | \exists \ a \in A :a > s-\epsilon $

Now, when using the $ \sup(A)=s$ as a given, I used an off negative on the condition so that for every $ \epsilon > 0 $ exists $ a \in A $ so that $a \leq s-\epsilon $

But using the fact that the supermum is the minimal upperbound, we get:
$$ s-\epsilon > s \rightarrow \epsilon < 0$$

Which is a contradiciton to the definition of epsilon whihc is defined to be a positive number.

Now, my problem is proving the other side, as is need in "if and only if" proofs (two sides of the statement need to be proven).

I'd also be happy to know if there's flaws during my proof. Thanks.

Comment: It's not correct. Let $]0,1]$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is $a$ s.t. $a>\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon$ but $\frac{1}{2}$ is not the supremum. You need that $s\geq a$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: I said that $s$ and an upperbound of $A $, in other words - $s \geq a $.

Comment: Anyone? Please...